# setting attribute undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This is example:

```
<%= atributo = "name" %>
<% @clients.each do |cli| %>
  <%= cli.atributo %>
<% end %>
```

Error undefined method 'atributo'

Answer (score 4):

That's not quite how Ruby works. For example:

```
attribute = "name"

client = Client.first
client.attribute # => Calls "attribute" method on client
```

What you want is to dynamically call a method:

```
attribute = "name"

client = Client.first
client.send(attribute) # => Calls "name" method on client.
```

Even better is to just read the attribute you want to manipulate:

```
attribute = "name"

client = Client.first
client[attribute] # => Value of "name" attribute
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is probably:

```
<% atributo = "name" %>
<% @clients.each do |cli| %>
   <%= clo[atributo] %>
<% end %>
```

So you call the method `#name` on the `cli` dynamically.

Comment: Actually, if that would be the intent you would need to do clo.send(attributo) Also, as I mentioned in my answer this sort of heavy business logic is probably better left off for the controller

Comment: @KalmanHazins this is a rails question so that's probably an `ActiveRecord` model and as such will support passing symbols and strings as keys to get the value of table columns. Why do you say it's "heavy business logic" if it just seems to be a dynamic way to render models on a view?

Comment: That's true. Given your assumptions - you are correct. Otherwise, doing metaprogramming in your view (with obj.send(:stuff)) is kinda gross. That could just be me...

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the method `atributo` on the `cli` object. If that object doesn't have the method, then you'll get the error.

What you're doing here is setting a local variable the the string "name" then iterating over some collection and calling some method on the object. I don't think that's what you were intending to do though. I would need more information to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

When you're defining `atributo`, it becomes a stand-alone variable, not related to any model.

When you're calling `cli.atributo`, you're trying to find the `atributo` method associated with the `cli` object, which doesn't exist. If you need `atributo` to be accessible from an object, define it in the model.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= atributo = "name" %>
```

is actually trying to print it out and the only way it can print it out is if there is a method atributo

Try

```
<% atributo = "name" %>
```

Or better still, set the value of attributo ( as in @attributo ) in your controller. The view should only be used for viewing, not actually setting variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you want:

```
<% @clients.each do |cli| %>
    <%= cli.name %>
<% end %>
```